# ContentLength in Not available for HttpWebRequest in Windows Phone 8.1 Universal Apps

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, runtime

I used the below code in that Content Length is not coming to HttpWebRequest. What is the alternative to that.

```
byte[]  buffer = ...request data as bytes
var webReq = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("http://127.0.0.1/target");

webReq.Method = "REQUIRED METHOD";
webReq.ContentType = "REQUIRED CONTENT TYPE";
webReq.ContentLength = buffer.Length;

var reqStream = webReq.GetRequestS`enter code here`tream();
reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
reqStream.Close();

var webResp = (HttpWebResponse) webReq.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some changes in WinRT API, so you can't find the ContentLength property in HttpWebRequest class. Instead, you need to choose to use IHttpContent.Headers .

You can check the following code for a quick reference:

```
Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient client = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient();
            var body = String.Format("body string");
            Windows.Web.Http.HttpStringContent theContent = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpStringContent(body, Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            theContent.Headers["Content-Length"] = "length";
            Windows.Web.Http.HttpResponseMessage aResponse = await client.PostAsync(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1/target"), theContent);
```